# Getting incorrect data while dividing 2 counters in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, alerts

I have created a Prometheus alert rule for dividing 2 counters

result -
`rate(istio_requests_total{app="serviceA",grpc_response_status=~"13"}[5m]) / rate(istio_requests_total{app="service-A"}[5m])` = 1

But the actual values are -

rate(istio_requests_total{app="serviceA",grpc_response_status=~"13"}[5m]) = 3.5

rate(istio_requests_total{app="service-A"}[5m]) = 74.5

the expected result is 0.046

Can anyone let me know where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Prometheus only performs math across similarly "shaped" (i.e. equivalent matching sets of labels). You're getting 1 as the result because, your query is dividing `rate(istio_requests_total)` where the labels match. Because you're filtering in the numerator, you're restricting the set of results to `app="serviceA",grpc_response_status=~"13"` but then Prometheus is dividing the equivalent metrics values by themselves i.e. X/X==1. What I think (!) you need to do is `sum without(grpc_response_status) (rate(...))` for both the numerator and denominator otherwise as you have them.

Comment: That way you'll get `grpc_response_status=~"13"` divided by `grpc_response_status` is anything which is, I think, what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus performs the `a / b` query in the following way:

1. It selects all the [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#time-series) for `a` query.
2. It selects all the time series for `b` query.
3. It drops names for time series found at steps 1 and 2.
4. For each time series at the left side of `/` it searches the time series with the same set of labels at the right side of `/`. If there is no matching time series found on the right side, then the time series on the left side is ignored.
5. It divides each pair of time series found at step 4. Actually, it divides individually every pair of points with the same timestamp for every pair of the matching time series.

See more details [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).

In your case the query at the left side selects a single time series with `{app="serviceA",grpc_response_status="13"}` labels, wile the query at the right side selects multiple time series, which contain the `{app="service-A"}` label, including the time series with `grpc_response_status="13"` label. So, it just divides the time series on the left side of `/` by itself and returns 1.

As I understood, you want calculating the share (percentage) of the time series on the left side to the sum of all the time series on the right side of `/`. Then the following query must be used:

```
rate(istio_requests_total{app="serviceA",grpc_response_status=~"13"}[5m])
  / on() group_left()
sum(rate(istio_requests_total{app="service-A"}[5m]))
```

This query uses the following promql features:

- `on()` modifier for limiting the set of labels used during searching for time series pairs at the step 4 above. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching)
- `group_left()` modifier for leaving all the labels from the left side after the division. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching)
- [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) function for summing all the time series on the right side of `/`.